# if/elsif/else Ruby error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Could someone tell me why this Ruby on Rails solution I came up with is returning the IF statement's output regardless of what'a written in the console?  (if you answer the question asked with "in Spanish" you still get a "Bonjour!" in return...

Assignment 2: Global Greetings

Ask the user how they would
like to be greeted.

If they say "in French", respond
with "Bonjour!"

If they say "in Spanish", respond
with "Hola!"

If they say "in Afrikaans", respond
with "Hallo!"

Handle all other input with "Uh, hi?"

```
puts "How would you like to be greated?"
greet = gets.chomp

if greet = "in French"
    puts "Bonjour!"
elsif greet = "in Spanish"
    puts "Hola!"
elsif greet = "in Afrikaans"
    puts "Hallo!"
else
    puts "Uh, hi?"
end
```

Comment: you're using single equals instead of double equals. Change `if greet =` to `if greet ==`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `=` you make an assignment.

You need a `==` like here:

```
puts "How would you like to be greated?"
greet = gets.chomp

if greet == "in French"
    puts "Bonjour!"
elsif greet == "in Spanish"
    puts "Hola!"
elsif greet == "in Afrikaans"
    puts "Hallo!"
else
    puts "Uh, hi?"
end
```

You can also use a `case` statement:

```
puts "How would you like to be greated?"
greet = gets.chomp

case greet 
when "in French"
    puts "Bonjour!"
when "in Spanish"
    puts "Hola!"
when "in Afrikaans"
    puts "Hallo!"
else
    puts "Uh, hi?"
end
```

If you use it in combination with a regular expression, you may also catch different spellings or sentences:

```
puts "How would you like to be greated?"
greet = gets.chomp

case greet 
when /French/i
    puts "Bonjour!"
when /Spanish/i
    puts "Hola!"
when /Afrikaans/i
    puts "Hallo!"
else
    puts "Uh, hi?"
end
```

Comment: The real solution is the `case` statement version. Not sure why you're indenting the first `when`, though. `case`/`when`/`end` should all be at the same indentation level according to virtually every Ruby style guide. One thing that would simplify the expressions here is `case greet.downcase` to avoid having to make each case-sensitive.

Comment: @tadman the first indention was just by accident when I recoded the if/elsif-version. I adapted it. My regular exceptions are defined case insensitive (option i in the regexp). The `case greet.downcase` would make it more obvious.

Comment: Yeah, I mean you can `downcase` once or put in `/i` many times. Doing the thing once is usually more concise.

Answer (score 0):

`=` is an assignment operator and `==` is used for comparison

```
if "in French" == "in French"  // returns true
    puts "Bonjour"
else
    puts "Uh, hi?"

value = 10 // assign 10 to the variable value
puts value //print 10
```